# I can't find imported Active Directory users

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, active-directory, site, active-directory-import

I have a Sharepoint 2013 Server in our DMZ (non-Domain joined). Then I configured an Active Directory Import from our LAN to this DMZ server (so that we have our domain credentials to connect to the sharepoint sites).

After the import, I could see the User profiles in user profile service application - manage user profiles. (Example:)
[image: User Backup]

Now I wanted to add this User to a Site. When I go to Site Settings - Site Permissions - Grant Permission I get the following error:

[image: Add User Error]

How can I add my users correctly to my Site? I really hope someone of you can help me.

EDIT: I share my screnario, so it's easier to understand.

I have a Sharepoint 2013 Server in our DMZ (non-Domain joined). Then I configured an Active Directory Import from our LAN to this DMZ server (so that we have our domain credentials to connect to the sharepoint sites). 
The server is accessable from the internet and the goal of the server is, to provide a data storage with onedrive for business.

Comment: Can you click on the red wavy line and see the account suggestions SharePoint makes?

Comment: Sure. It says "No results found". I think that I have to configure something else after the AD import, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: It could be that since your SharePoint server is not domain joined, the domain is not automatically added to the people picker.  Try running STSADM.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv “domain:aaa.com;domain:bbb.com” -url http://webappurl

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your scenario. Who must get access to OneDrive for Business? External people, employees of your company, or both?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, I appreciate that. @Mheld:
Employees and customers are using the Onedrive for business in the future. They have both active directory accounts in our domain

Comment: @James Grizzle: I tried this out for my web application with the command STSADM.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv “kueba.ch” -url https://kbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Now It takes like 2 Minutes when I press the button to invite someone to the site, but it's the same errors as always. But I think you are right with people ticker, maybe I have to configure something with it (but with other command properties)

Comment: If both of them already have an AD-Account in your domain, my recommendation below is exactly what you need. Implementing WAP is not the easiest job, but it's worth the effort. If you have F5 or Netscaler with Preauthentication module licensed, you may also use them instead.

Comment: During the 2 minutes between when you hit find and before the error shows up, do you see any errors in the ULS log?  Also, I 100% agree with @MHeld, a proxy is a much better way to go then exposing SharePoint through the DMZ.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, providing access to SharePoint OnPremise over the internet is not an easy job. Especially if you want to make it secure and user-friendly.

It is not enough just to get a profile in UserProfile Service. If you want to give access to a SharePoint site, a user must have an account in one of the following things:

- Active Directory (Requires SharePoint to be domain-joined)
- FBA Membership provider (Stores Users in SQL-Database or LDAP-Directory instead of AD - requires FBA-configuration. I say FBA is a [false friend](http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2009/06/13/sharepoint-fbalinks-and-limitations/). It is easy to configure, but has a lot of drawbacks in everyday use)
- ADFS Federation (Hard to configure)

Unfortunately you didn't describe your scenario, but this might be a solution for you:

- Optional: Move your SharePoint-Server to your LAN if internal users must have access
- Join it to your existing ActiveDirectory Domain. Manage your user-accounts there.
- Publish your SharePoint-Site to the Internet with a reverse-proxy like [WebApplicationProxy](https://www.brightstarr.com/sharepoint-technology-and-application-insights/blog/securely-publishing-sharepoint-externally-using-web-application-proxy). WAP includes a proxy-role running in DMZ to achieve security and user-friendly login with a HTML-Form.